# Volume of torus

Tags: calculus

I wanna calculate the volume of a torus that is created when the circlearea $(x-4)^2+y^2 \leq 4$ revolves around the y-axis. I don't understand what the difference would be if I calculated the volume of the circle $(x-4)^2+y^2=4$ revolving around the y-axis. Doesn't the circlearea just create a solid torus instead of a hollow? 
Then comes the practical problem of finding a formula for the volume. My idea is that if the distance from the "right" and "left" side of the circle to origo is R and r respectively, then the area of the thin circles that constitute the torus is $\pi(R^2-r^2)$. Then the height is dy and so we integrate from, if x denotes the radius of the circle, -r to r. Would this work?

Comment: @Crostul Yes, changed it now.

Comment: By [Pappus's centroid theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem), the volume and surface area of the torus are $(\pi\cdot 2^2)(2 \pi\cdot 4)$ and $(2\pi\cdot 2)(2 \pi\cdot 4)$ respectively, both of them equal to $32\pi^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$V = \pi\int_{-2}^{2}\left(4+\sqrt{(4-y^2)}\right)^2-\left(4-\sqrt{(4-y^2)}\right)^2dy$$

Outer radius $= 4+\sqrt{4-y^2}$

Inner radius $ = 4-\sqrt{4-y^2}$

$$V = \int_{-2}^{2}\left(16\pi\sqrt{4-y^2}\right)dy$$

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-y^2}dy = 2\pi$$

$$V = 16\pi*2\pi = 32\pi^2$$